# How to get more High-Quality Questions for this Site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, questions

This site answers practically all questions, but doesn't get so many visitors or questions per day. (See stats [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435).) How can we get more high-quality questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps we can encourage bloggers and others to ask questions here that they plan on answering themselves. This can get a discussion started about a certain topic, and then (perhaps after further research), they can answer their own question.

Comment: wow that sounds like a riddle but only Issac is allowed to do that

Comment: The problem with riddles is that they're looking for trick answers. Its accepted on all stackexchange sites that you can answer your own questions.

Comment: @ArielK, yes, or, perhaps better, that they deliberately exclude information the asker has (and, when he thought of the question, had) that would help answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

Please take a look at the [promotion tag](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/promotion) here in meta. There are a whole bunch of ideas in there for ways we can spread the word about this site. Anything you can do to help with any of them, or any additional ideas you could add, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Issac, the link is not working currently, it should be [meta-tag:promotion], right now it links to the main site, you need to use "meta-tag" in place of "tag:"

Comment: @Kaveh, thanks. I accidentally linked to the "promotion" tag on main. I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 4):

We need to increase the traffic to the site. Right now it is not as much as it should be. One of the main reasons is that the site does not show up in top search engine results when someone searches for a topic related to Jewish life and Judaism, so I am guessing that we are not getting a reasonable portion of traffic from them (Issac could you please check the analytics data and confirm?). We need to increase the rank of Judaism.SE on search engines. Here are few things that we can do:

- add a link to the site to the Wikipedia articles: [Judaism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaism), [Jews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jews), [Israelites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israelites)
- linking to the site from our personal websites (e.g. by putting our flair, you can find it under flair tab on your profile)
- if somehow someone links to the site in an article from a high rank website like a CNN or BBC it would help a lot in increasing the rank of the site

Comment: Maybe someone from the site can rob a bank ~

Comment: @Ariel, :) I was thinking of a more reasonable way of ending up on these sites.